# @WebServlet Message The requested resource [/demo_war_exploded/hello-servlet] is not available

Tags: java, jsp

Java Servlet Page[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JAHof.png)

Comment: I strongly recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Yes, you should copy/paste code into the question